# Lemma for Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to understand the following lemma for FTOFAG
[image]

In the book, The proof is by induction：

We proceed by induction on $|G|$. Clearly, the case where $|G| = p$ is true. Now suppose the statement is true for all Abelian groups of order less than $|G|$.

I am trying to see why $|G| = p $ is true. Also why are we assuming all abelian groups of order less than $|G|$? Aren't we looking at prime-power order? So $p^1, p^2, p^3, ....$

The rest of the proof is the following:
[image]

Also why is $m^\prime$ and $n^\prime$ the largest integer such that $|H_i| > p$ and $|K_i| > p$?

" $|G^p| < |G|$, we have by induction $m^\prime = n^\prime$. " What happened here? The author skipped some step so I am very confused. What are the induction step???

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun This is Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph Gallian

Comment: I thought so, @Cup. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: If $G$ has order $p$, then the only way to write it as a product of nontrivial factors is as $C_p$, the cyclic group of order $p$ (the product of the orders of the factors is $p$, which is a prime).  As to the second part, “all groups of smaller order” here is a gloss for “all abelian groups whose order is a prime power and is strictly smaller than $|G|$”.

Comment: The result is definitely correct as stated. But a better formulation would speak not in terms of $\lvert H_{i+1} \rvert \le \lvert H_{i} \rvert$, but equivalently in terms of $\lvert H_{i+1} \rvert$ dividing $\lvert H_{i} \rvert$, because the latter formulation then holds for an arbitrary finite abelian group.